# Bash - Pass multiple array arguments from script

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments, code-coverage, xcodebuild

I am using [XcodeCoverageConverter](https://github.com/twittemb/XcodeCoverageConverter) to convert XCResult to Cobertura XML as per the instruction provided in the README file.
It is working as expected when only one item was passed as value for `--exclude-packages`.
However when I try to pass an array as follows,

```
xcc generate coverage.json TargetDirectory cobertura-xml --exclude-packages Tests AnotherPackageName --verbose
```

I get the following error,

```
Error: The value 'AnotherPackageName' is invalid for '<output-formats>'
Usage: xcc generate <json-file> <output-path> [<output-formats> ...] [--exclude-targets <exclude-targets> ...] [--exclude-packages <exclude-packages> ...] [--verbose]
```

Same thing I am trying from my Bash script, where I get the same error if I pass array for `--exclude-packages`.

**Sample 1**

```
jsonPath="coverage.json"
coberturaTargetPath="Cobertura"

xcc generate $jsonPath \
   $coberturaTargetPath cobertura-xml \
   --exclude-packages Tests AnotherPackageName \
   --verbose
```

**Sample 2**

```
jsonPath="coverage.json"
coberturaTargetPath="Cobertura"
excludePackages=(Tests AnotherPackageName)

xcc generate $jsonPath \
   $coberturaTargetPath cobertura-xml \
   --exclude-packages ${excludePackages[@]} \
   --verbose
```

**Sample 3**

```
jsonPath="coverage.json"
coberturaTargetPath="Cobertura"
excludePackages=(Tests AnotherPackageName)

xcc generate $jsonPath \
   $coberturaTargetPath cobertura-xml \
   --exclude-packages=${excludePackages[@]} \
   --verbose
```

**Sample 4**

```
jsonPath="coverage.json"
coberturaTargetPath="Cobertura"
outputFormats=(cobertura-xml)
excludePackages=(Tests AnotherPackageName)

xcc generate $jsonPath \
   $coberturaTargetPath ${outputFormats[@]} \
   --exclude-packages=${excludePackages[@]} \
   --verbose
```

**Sample 5**

```
jsonPath="coverage.json"
coberturaTargetPath="Cobertura"
outputFormats=(cobertura-xml)
excludePackages=(Tests AnotherPackageName)

xcc generate $jsonPath \
   $coberturaTargetPath ${outputFormats[@]} \
   --exclude-packages="${excludePackages[@]} " \
   --verbose
```

In all the above attempts, I am getting the same error.
The items (excluding first item) which I pass for --exclude-packages is considered for output-formats.
How to fix this?

**Update:**

xcc utility does support multiple arguments for `--exclude-packages`. [Reference](https://github.com/twittemb/XcodeCoverageConverter/blob/3e668c2b0a9aed9bbc67391d1f9e64232e8edb40/Sources/XcodeCoverageConverter/main.swift#L30)

Comment: Based on your suggestion I tried `--exclude-packages="${excludePackages[@]} "` where I get the same error. When I try with `--exclude-packages "Tests AnotherPackageName"` it considers it as array with 1 element "Tests AnotherPackageName"

Comment: How would you run it without using array at all? Would you do `--exclude-packages something --exclude-packages somethingelse`? In other words, what does `xcc` utility expect to have when user wants to pass multiple arguments to `exclude-packages` and does `xcc` utility support such use case?

Comment: Yes `xcc` utility supports multiple arguments, here is the reference [link](https://github.com/twittemb/XcodeCoverageConverter/blob/3e668c2b0a9aed9bbc67391d1f9e64232e8edb40/Sources/XcodeCoverageConverter/main.swift#L30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net .

Assuming `xcc` utility supports multiple `--exclude-packages` arguments, then: for each array element, add --exclude-packages before each array element, then pass it to the command.

```
excludePackages=(Tests AnotherPackageName)

cmd=(
    xcc generate
    "$jsonPath"
    "$coberturaTargetPath"
    "${outputFormats[@]}"
)
for ii in "${excludePackages[@]}"; do
   cmd+=(--exclude-packages "$ii")
done
cmd+=(--verbose)

echo "Running: ${cmd[*]}"
"${cmd[@]}"
```